# Is this XML file correct for RSS feeding?

Tags: php, xml, rss, cdata

I am generating a XML-RSS type file from PHP.

The output for example is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
    <title>Mi web mola</title>
    <link>http://www.dominio.com/blog.php</link>
    <language>es-ES</language>
    <description>Mallas y eso</description>
    <generator>Autor</generator>

     <item>
      <title>Articulo de prueba</title>
      <link>http://www.midominio.com/2342</link>
      <pubDate>14/06/2010</pubDate>
      <description><![CDATA[Descripcion de prueba bla bla bla]]></description>
      <content:encoded><![CDATA[Contenido prueba]]></content:encoded>
     </item>

 </channel>
</rss>
```

... and all I can see in the Firefox preview is the title and the description of the blog, not the items, but in the source it appears correctly, so I've thought it must be a parse error or something like that..

What could be wrong?

Again, excuse me for my bad english, and thank you very much.

Comment: Can you not use CDATA section?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what do you mean.. I am using it for encoding the description and the content.. what's wrong?

Comment: (Aside not relevant to question: CDATA sections are generally questionable. Surrounding some text content with `<![CDATA[`...`]]>` does not ensure that it's properly encoded: what if the text contained the `]]>` sequence of characters? Given that you have to escape at least that one case even *with* a CDATA section, you're not really gaining much in comparison with doing a normal XML `&`->`&amp;`,`<`->`&lt;`,`>`->`&gt;` replacement.)

Comment: ok, good point, i'll take care of it, thanks.

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org/ is your friend for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your RSS problem, but as it stands that isn't valid XML-with-namespaces.

If you want to use a `<content:encoded>` element, you should declare a namespace for the prefix `content`.

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
```

Also `pubDate` should be in RFC822 format, eg. `Mon, 14 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT`.

Comment: thanks!! that was it!! anyway i'll make a note of what bobince said, but it's already working.

Comment: ehm.. i have just realized that YOU are bobince, the same who commented about questionable use of CDATA sections.. sorry :-|